# Microphone permission for firefox browser addons/extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

Recently working on a browser extensions which needs microphone access. Was able to make it work on chrome no problem with that. However firefox seems not working as expected.

Upon installation we are prompting for mic access firefox allow it temporarily. Tried to allow it manually no luck. `media.navigator.permission.disabled` to true is working but that not an option cause in future no prompt will be there to allow or block the access.

```
Extension structure...
content.js
background.js (Which requires the access)
popup.js (from where looking for the access)
```

Is there any way to gain microphone access for firefox addons/extension?

Thanks for your help.

Note: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-mic-input-permissions-and-speech-recognition-in-chrome-extensions-ff7e3ca84cb0 this tutorial works for chrome. Is there something similar for firefox as well?

Comment: Popup get the access but we need it in `background`. Moreover popup only get temporary access upon closing it resets everything. Found this thread https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1278100 seems they don't allow it in background.